# Multiple conditions in mongo regex query

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to match all documents where `Url` field in db contains both `should` and `match`, in any order.

In example, those should match:

`http://www.myurl.com/should/match`

`http://www.myurl.com/match/should`

But not `http://www.myurl.com/no/match`

I tried several regex, but no match. I.e:

```
db.mycollection.find({"Url":/^(?=.*\should\b)(?=.*\match\b).*$/})
```

Returns no matches.

Appreciate any help.
Best Regards

Comment: will one always follow the other or could there be a gap like `should/you/match`?

Comment: @depperm could be gap. They should be present anywhere in string.

Comment: I can't test this right now but what about `"Url":/.*should\/(.+\/)?match|.*match\/(.+\/)?should/`

Comment: @depperm Not working

Comment: can you share more of your mongo document so we can see if there is anything unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the beginning boundaries of those words in your regex with `\b` as you have set the ending boundaries

```
db.mycollection.find( { "Url": /^(?=.*\bshould\b)(?=.*\bmatch\b).*$/ } )
```

On collection of documents

```
{ "Url" : "http://www.myurl.com/should/match" }
{ "Url" : "http://www.myurl.com/match/should" }
{ "Url" : "http://www.myurl.com/no/match" }
```

it returns

```
{ "Url" : "http://www.myurl.com/should/match" }
{ "Url" : "http://www.myurl.com/match/should" }
```

Comment: Check again, I used `url` instead of `Url`

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: "Script executed sucessfully, but there are no results to show", it says. But documents ARE there.

Comment: Do you call it on the proper collection?